# fpm delay deal with the request

Tags: php, nginx

I have a question ask for help. when i use php-fpm-5.3.6 with nginx  to accept  http request,  but I find my request is delay 20ms before php-fpm to deal. how I can do to resolve the problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMQ3Z.jpg)

Comment: The first thing you should do is to upgrade your PHP version. 5.3.6 is _old_ and haven't gotten any updates (including security updates) for _8 years_ now.

Comment: thanks. I upgrade my PHP version to 7.4, but there is steal a problem is that php-fpm do nothing but  still spends 10 ms time to make response.(8C 16G). I want to known why php-fpm framework take so much time(10 ms) without any business work.(I use curl to request local php app)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: i find out the answer. this reason this my framework has so much business logic to deal , so the php per request  will reload it ,thus it's my fault.